Firebase cloud function error when deploying
I get this error when I try to deploy the function (I tried both my original function and a test function to make sure the code has nothing to do with the error) my node version is v18.20.4 and cloud functions use node v18 too so I don't know I tried to remove the node modules and package lock json and run npm install but still get the same error and in an older project I got the same error too (but this project discontinued so I didn't solve it) anyone knows what's wrong?
NOTE it works fine in local mode by running firebase emulators:start
yomna@192 functions % firebase deploy --only functions:testFunction


=== Deploying to 'wright-f2632'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8012

i  extensions: ensuring required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  extensions: required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/yomna/Coding/Mobile Apps/Work/wright/functions (34.11 KB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function testFunction(us-central1)...
Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: npm error code EUSAGE
npm error
npm error `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm error
npm error Missing: jest@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/core@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/types@29.6.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: import-local@3.2.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-cli@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/console@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/reporters@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/test-result@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/transform@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: ansi-escapes@4.3.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: chalk@4.1.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: ci-info@3.9.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: exit@0.1.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: graceful-fs@4.2.11 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-changed-files@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-config@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-haste-map@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-message-util@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-regex-util@29.6.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-resolve@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-resolve-dependencies@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-runner@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-runtime@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-snapshot@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-util@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-validate@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-watcher@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: micromatch@4.0.8 from lock file
npm error Missing: pretty-format@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: slash@3.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @bcoe/v8-coverage@0.2.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jridgewell/trace-mapping@0.3.25 from lock file
npm error Missing: collect-v8-coverage@1.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: glob@7.2.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: istanbul-lib-coverage@3.2.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: istanbul-lib-instrument@6.0.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: istanbul-lib-report@3.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: istanbul-lib-source-maps@4.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: istanbul-reports@3.1.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-worker@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: string-length@4.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: v8-to-istanbul@9.3.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@2.0.6 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/core@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: babel-plugin-istanbul@6.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: convert-source-map@2.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: fast-json-stable-stringify@2.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: pirates@4.0.6 from lock file
npm error Missing: write-file-atomic@4.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: @ampproject/remapping@2.3.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/code-frame@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/generator@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helper-compilation-targets@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helper-module-transforms@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helpers@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/parser@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/template@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/traverse@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/types@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: debug@4.3.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: gensync@1.0.0-beta.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: json5@2.2.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: semver@6.3.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jridgewell/gen-mapping@0.3.5 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/highlight@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: picocolors@1.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jsesc@3.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/compat-data@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helper-validator-option@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: browserslist@4.24.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: lru-cache@5.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: semver@6.3.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helper-module-imports@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helper-simple-access@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helper-validator-identifier@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: chalk@2.4.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: js-tokens@4.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: debug@4.3.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: globals@11.12.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helper-string-parser@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: to-fast-properties@2.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/schemas@29.6.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/istanbul-reports@3.0.4 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/yargs@17.0.33 from lock file
npm error Missing: @sinclair/typebox@0.27.8 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jridgewell/set-array@1.2.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec@1.5.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jridgewell/resolve-uri@3.1.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/istanbul-lib-report@3.0.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/yargs-parser@21.0.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: type-fest@0.21.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/helper-plugin-utils@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @istanbuljs/load-nyc-config@1.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @istanbuljs/schema@0.1.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: istanbul-lib-instrument@5.2.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: test-exclude@6.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: camelcase@5.3.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: find-up@4.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: get-package-type@0.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: js-yaml@3.14.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: resolve-from@5.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: caniuse-lite@1.0.30001667 from lock file
npm error Missing: electron-to-chromium@1.5.32 from lock file
npm error Missing: node-releases@2.0.18 from lock file
npm error Missing: update-browserslist-db@1.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: supports-color@7.2.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: path-exists@4.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: fs.realpath@1.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: inflight@1.0.6 from lock file
npm error Missing: minimatch@3.1.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: path-is-absolute@1.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: pkg-dir@4.2.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: resolve-cwd@3.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: make-dir@4.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: debug@4.3.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: source-map@0.6.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: html-escaper@2.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: execa@5.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: cross-spawn@7.0.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: get-stream@6.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: human-signals@2.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: merge-stream@2.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: npm-run-path@4.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: onetime@5.1.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: signal-exit@3.0.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: strip-final-newline@2.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: path-key@3.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: shebang-command@2.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: which@2.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: create-jest@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: prompts@2.4.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/test-sequencer@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: babel-jest@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: deepmerge@4.3.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-circus@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-environment-node@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-get-type@29.6.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: parse-json@5.2.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: strip-json-comments@3.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/babel__core@7.20.5 from lock file
npm error Missing: babel-preset-jest@29.6.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/babel__generator@7.6.8 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/babel__template@7.4.4 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/babel__traverse@7.20.6 from lock file
npm error Missing: babel-plugin-jest-hoist@29.6.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: babel-preset-current-node-syntax@1.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators@7.8.4 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-bigint@7.8.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@7.12.13 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-class-static-block@7.14.5 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta@7.10.4 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-json-strings@7.8.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-logical-assignment-operators@7.10.4 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.8.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-numeric-separator@7.10.4 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.8.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.8.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@7.8.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-private-property-in-object@7.14.5 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await@7.14.5 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/environment@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/expect@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: co@4.6.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: dedent@1.5.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: is-generator-fn@2.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-each@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-matcher-utils@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: pure-rand@6.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: stack-utils@2.0.6 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/fake-timers@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-mock@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: expect@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @sinonjs/fake-timers@10.3.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @sinonjs/commons@3.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: type-detect@4.0.8 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/expect-utils@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/graceful-fs@4.1.9 from lock file
npm error Missing: anymatch@3.1.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: fb-watchman@2.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: fsevents@2.3.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: walker@1.0.8 from lock file
npm error Missing: normalize-path@3.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: picomatch@2.3.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: bser@2.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: node-int64@0.4.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-diff@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: diff-sequences@29.6.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: @types/stack-utils@2.0.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-pnp-resolver@1.2.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: resolve@1.22.8 from lock file
npm error Missing: resolve.exports@2.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: emittery@0.13.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-docblock@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: jest-leak-detector@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: source-map-support@0.5.13 from lock file
npm error Missing: detect-newline@3.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/globals@29.7.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @jest/source-map@29.6.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: cjs-module-lexer@1.4.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: strip-bom@4.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: callsites@3.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.25.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: natural-compare@1.4.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: camelcase@6.3.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: leven@3.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: supports-color@8.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: argparse@1.0.10 from lock file
npm error Missing: esprima@4.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: sprintf-js@1.0.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: braces@3.0.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: fill-range@7.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: to-regex-range@5.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11 from lock file
npm error Missing: balanced-match@1.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: concat-map@0.0.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: mimic-fn@2.1.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: error-ex@1.3.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: json-parse-even-better-errors@2.3.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: lines-and-columns@1.2.4 from lock file
npm error Missing: is-arrayish@0.2.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: ansi-styles@5.2.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: react-is@18.3.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: kleur@3.0.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: sisteransi@1.0.5 from lock file
npm error Missing: is-core-module@2.15.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: path-parse@1.0.7 from lock file
npm error Missing: supports-preserve-symlinks-flag@1.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: shebang-regex@3.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: buffer-from@1.1.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: escape-string-regexp@2.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: char-regex@1.0.2 from lock file
npm error Missing: has-flag@4.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: is-number@7.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: makeerror@1.0.12 from lock file
npm error Missing: tmpl@1.0.5 from lock file
npm error Missing: isexe@2.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: imurmurhash@0.1.4 from lock file
npm error Missing: ms@2.1.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: yallist@3.1.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: ansi-styles@3.2.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 from lock file
npm error Missing: supports-color@5.5.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: color-convert@1.9.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: color-name@1.1.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: has-flag@3.0.0 from lock file
npm error Missing: ms@2.1.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: semver@6.3.1 from lock file
npm error Missing: ms@2.1.3 from lock file
npm error Missing: p-try@2.2.0 from lock file
npm error
npm error Clean install a project
npm error
npm error Usage:
npm error npm ci
npm error
npm error Options:
npm error [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
npm error [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm error [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm error [--strict-peer-deps] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit]
npm error [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm error [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm error [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm error
npm error aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm error
npm error Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2024-10-07T12_00_42_243Z-debug-0.log. For more details see the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-central1/4c78ff4b-6052-4453-8fd4-395f4126cffa?project=847150081881.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        testFunction(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/wright-f2632/us/gcf

Error: There was an error deploying functions

Here this is my package json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^4.3.2",
    "diff": "^7.0.0",
    "fastest-levenshtein": "^1.0.16",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


Have you tried installing the packages one after the other?
Also, have you tried upgrading to Node v20?

Yes I did the only thing that worked was removing package-lock.json before deploying
